# Preventing elastic scrolling on OS X Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to prevent the elastic scrolling that occurs on OS X in both Chrome and Safari.

If you don't understand what I mean, it's when you scroll up while the page is at the top, or down when the page is at the bottom, and it shows a gray background behind the page.

There is a css solution for single page apps where you just add `overflow:hidden` to the `html` or `body`

However, I need to be able to scroll.

I've come up with a solution using Javascript (JQuery), but it's only for scrolling passed the top, and only works for chrome. Also, it's a bit buggy in Safari.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
   scrollAmount = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(scrollAmount < 1){
      $(this).scrollTop(1);
   }
});
```

So that's just checking of the user scrolls below 1 meaning they try to scroll up passed where the page ends. I tried 0 but that didn't work.
I haven't been able to find a way to check if the user scrolls passed the bottom of the page.

So any thoughts?

Edit:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
   scrollAmount = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(scrollAmount < 1){
      $(this).scrollTop(1);
   }
   if(scrollAmount > $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      $(this).scrollTop($(window).height());
   }
});
```

Now I've added a check for if we scroll passed the bottom of the page. This method is not working though, it's bouncing around very ungracefully.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this? I find that that little bit of UI is a clear indicator that I have no more to scroll but also that it's still working (i.e. not frozen). People aren't paid lots of money to think about these things for no reason.

Comment: I'd also question why you want to do this. If users don't want this behavior, [it is possible to disable it](http://lifehacker.com/5909402/turn-off-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x-lion) (unfortunately, not via UI). If you do force this, test for the case where people have turned it off!

Comment: I'm making a site where things happen depending on the scroll amount. When the user scrolls passed the end of the page it causes things to look a little choppy. Not a huge bug, but I'm trying to make things look really solid.

Answer (score 8):

You can now use [`overscroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior):

```css
html, body {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Comment: Apologies - I did misread that!

Comment: This isn't fully supported in Safari yet :'(

Comment: Doesn't work on safari macos

Comment: It's in preview in Safari 16.

Comment: It works on Firefox on Mac M2

Comment: The overscroll behaviour is especially annoying in conjunction with `position: sticky` in a table header.  This fixes it - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

When you quickly scroll up to the top, the elastic browser causes the scroll top to become negative. Using the st <= 0, will make sure no action is taken when this happens.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var dh = $(document).height(),
        wh = $(window).height(),
        st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (st <= 0) {
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    } else if (st + wh >= dh) {
        $(this).scrollTop(dh);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain your solution in one or two sentences. I personally could live with that but the "SO community" does not like code-only answers.

Answer (score -1):

While I dislike the methodology, you can use jQuery to get the document height (and thus the bottom of the page for the scroll distance using `$(document).height();`)

Another method would be to wrap the entire page with a `<div id="preventScroll"></div>` wrapper, with the property `overflow: scroll; height: 100%; width: 100%;`

That would be a separate scrolling device and prevent your whole issue.

Comment: That's not going to be exact. The height of the document does not correlate to the amount you've scrolled.

Comment: Can you prove this method? What's stopping the wrapper from being scrolled? When its contents are at top or bottom and the user pulls whichever respective way where there is no more, the wrapper should still pull with its contents in tow to reveal the void that OP wants to hide. EDIT: oh, overflow scroll might work.

Comment: Popnoodles: Yeah, valid point. I haven't tested it yet (on a PC right now).

Comment: Kolby, the $(document).height() - $(window).height() (viewport height) should give you what you need. Since it cannot scroll any further than that.